# Is this object wrapping method commonly used or bad practice?

Tags: c#

I have 2 arrays, `smallArray` and `bigArray`, for example

```
 void myFun(TypeA a, TypeA b, TypeA c, TypeA d)
 {
      TypeA[] smallArray = new TypeA[]{a,b,c,d}
      TypeA[] bigArray = new TypeA[]{a,b,a,b,c,c,c,d,d,a,c,b,d,a,d,...}
 }
```

`bigArray` only contains members which is from `smallArray`. Now I would like to exchange all the objects in `bigArray`, but keeping the structural order, and minimize the number of operations.

e.g., my ideal outcome would be `{aa,bb,aa,bb,cc,cc,cc,dd,dd,aa,cc,bb,dd,aa,dd,...}` where `aa` ... are new objects of `TypeA`

So I redesign my code into this:

```
class TypeB
{
    public TypeA Value {get; set;}
}

void myFun(TypeB a2, TypeB b2, TypeB c2, TypeB d2) // where a2.Value = a, b2.Value = b...
{
    TypeB[] smallArray = new TypeB[]{a2,b2,c2,d2}
    TypeB[] bigArray = new TypeB[]{a2,b2,a2,b2,c2,c2,c2,d2,d2,a2,c2,b2,d2,a2,d2,...}
}
```

I "box" the target object into a wrapper, and store the wrapped objects in arrays. Now when I update the values of objects in `smallArray`, values of members in `bigArray` get updated at the same time.

Is this technique commonly used? or are there any other ways to simplify it?

#### Update

Now `TypeA` becomes `string` so that you can at least understand the question.

I have 2 arrays, `smallArray` and `bigArray`, for example

```
string[] smallArray = new string[] {"a","b","c","d"}
string[] bigArray = new string[] {"a","b","a","b","c","c","c","d","d","a","c","b","d","a","d",...}
```

`bigArray` only contains members which is from `smallArray`. Now I would like to exchange  all the objects in `bigArray`, but keeping the structural order, and minimize the number of operations.

e.g., my ideal new bigArry would become `{"aa","bb","aa","bb","cc","cc","cc","dd","dd","aa","cc","bb","dd","aa","dd",...}`

So I redesign my code into this:

```
class TypeB
{
    public string Value {get; set;}
}

void myFun(TypeB a2, TypeB b2, TypeB c2, TypeB d2) // where a2.Value = "a", b2.Value = "b"...
{
    TypeB[] smallArray = new TypeB[]{a2,b2,c2,d2}
    TypeB[] bigArray = new TypeB[]{a2,b2,a2,b2,c2,c2,c2,d2,d2,a2,c2,b2,d2,a2,d2,...}
}
```

I "box" the `string` into a wrapper, and store the wrapped objects in arrays. Now when I update the values of objects in `smallArray`, values of members in `bigArray` get updated at the same time.

So in example i only need to update 4 objects instead of the whole `bigArray`.

Is this technique commonly used? or are there any other ways to simplify it?

Comment: more detail on class TypeA, what property you want to update

Comment: What are a, b, c, d .. ?

Comment: @colinfang: could you show your current code which uses *boxing*

Comment: Are you talking about a "Has A" relationship?

Comment: @Jodrell  yes, I thought my `TypeB`  perfectly clearly shows it has a `TypeA`

Comment: My problem with this is it's totally not obvious what's going on. seems like a lot of messing about to not duplicate four references. I'd have one array of the thingies, and then something to return a big array or small array from it, I'be probably implement the ordering in those methods as well, to make it explicit and testable.

Comment: I read your post two times, but i have no idea what you question is about. Is TypeA a struct or a class?

Comment: It looks like you're talking about pointers. You're using the small array to store 4 special object wrappers. Each of these has a pointer to an object. Let's just assume TypeA is String, and the first array contains 4 Type B Objects pointing to "printer", "monitor", "keyboard" and "mouse". The second big array points to these 4 Type B objects for ordering and counting. I think you should take a look at linked list - but I don't dare to post this as answer.

Comment: Are you asking, what is a reference type?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, that answer is "Yes, you can do that". An easier way would probably be having bigArray be of type int, and just store indices into smallArray:

```
TypeB[] smallArray = new TypeB[] { a2, b2, c2, d2 };
int[] bigArray = new int[] { 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3 };
```

This way, the level indirection stays the same for bigArray, but you don't have any indirection for smallArray. Additionally, this enforces that bigArray doesn't contain any elements that aren't in smallArray (except for indices that are out of bounds).

To be able to say more you should provide us a more detailed description of the use case. Is your application performace-critical? How about memory contraints?

Comment: No memory constraints, it is hard to say whether or not perfermance-critical, as less operations is always better than more given that the code is still relatively readable and concise

Comment: In practice my `smallArray` is a 2d array, so if i store indices i have to store tuples of indices, and access the object via `smallArray[x][y]` that's an extra indirection.

Comment: If you know the dimensions, you can easily translate two coordinates into one by using the index `smallArray[y * size + x]`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Every list or array stores pointers. When you point these pointers at a commonly know place, i. e. at a property of a retained object in memory, no matter if this is maintained as a Singleton, or in an array or a static variable, you can exchange the "wrapped" object at a central place. Without a proper example, this is not a commonly used practice, but I can imagine there are suitable situations to do this.

Comment: what about arrays of value types?

Comment: how would `linked list` help in such case?

Comment: @Jodrell What do you mean? If I like them or not?

Comment: @colinfang You're right, I confused this. Has nothing to do with linked lists at all, but can't edit out now.

Comment: @Akku, is the assertion "Every list or array stores pointers" true for arrays of value types?

Answer (score 0):

If I declare a reference type,

```
 class SomeClass
 {
 }
```

Then instantiate a variable to it,

```
 var someInstance = new SomeClass()
```

then declare another variable like this,

```
 var someInstance2 = someInstance
```

there is only one instance of `SomeClass` in memory but I have two variables `someInstance` and `someInstance2` that reference or point to that `SomeClass` instance.

---

So, if I declare two new instances of `SomeClass`, note the `new` keyword,

```
var a = new SomeClass();
var b = new SomeClass();
```

then use them to initialise two new arrays

```
var smallArray = new SomeClass[] { a, b }
var bigArray = new SomeClass[] { a, b, a, a, b, b, b, a }
```

I have instantiated only two new instances of `SomeClass`. I have made two new arrays containing a sum of ten references or pointers but no extra `SomeClass` references.

The only time a new instance of a reference type is created is when the `new` keyword is used (there are some irrelavent exceptions.)
Is this helping?

---

So, if I want to substitute all the members of an array for some other member I could write a function like this,

```
public static class ArrayExtension
{
    void Substitute<T>(this T[] array, IDictionary<T, T> subsitute)
    {
         for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
         {
              if (substitute.ContainsKey(array[i])
              {
                  array[i] = substitute[array[i]];   
              }
         }
    } 
}
```

which I could call like this,

```
var substitutes = new Dictionary
    {
        { Key = a, Value = aa },
        { Key = b, Value = bb },
        { Key = c, Value = cc },
        { Key = d, Value = dd }
    }

bigArray.Substitute(substitutes);
```